# How to get streamArn of a manually created dynamodb table in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a cloudformation template to deploy a lambda and this lambda will have DynamoDB as trigger. So, to accommodate that I am using AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping in my cloudformation template and hardcoding EventSourceArn for each dynamodb table.

My question, is there any way to get streamArn of a existing DynamoDB table, which is created manually? or I have to pass this value hardcoded from parameter section.

Please help me with you advice.

Comment: you can make an existing resource part of your cloudformation template. or pass the arn manually.

Comment: I don't want to include the DynamoDB table in my resource section and this table has not created through stack so can not use export/import either. I could use Fn::Join but the stream arn has timestamp so I am rethinking about the alternatives. Yes we can have that hardcoded arn, but looking for ways to get arn by passing the dynamoDb table name.

Comment: i dont think there is a simple solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the things you create manually are available in AWS console and you could check all arns.

For you specific case go to `AWS Console -> DynamoDB -> Select your table`.

[image]

Note: I would recommend using cloudformation and avoid using manual things if this is deployed somewhere for real.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native CloudFormation functionality to retrieve the manually created resource Arns with the exception of [certain parameter types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types).

If you intend to keep this resource as a manually created resource you would need to pass in as a parameter into your template so that you can reference it, either referencing as a string or a [SSM based parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-ssm-parameter-types).

Alternatively you could construct a [Custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) that accepts the DynamoDB table name as a parameter and triggers a Lambda to get the Arn of the stream.

If you wanted to managed the table in CloudFormation you could construct the resource in your CloudFormation template and then [import into the stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html). By doing this you could then reference the `StreamArn` of the [DynamoDB table resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html).